# description - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, resteasy

I am trying to learn RESTful web services using mkyoung tutorials. I was trying to execute my first application, but I got "HTTP Status 404. The requested resource is not available" errors.

Here is my `.java` file content:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class exeClass {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }

}
```

My `web.xml` file:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I am trying to enter >> `http://localhost:8080/RestEasyExmp/rest/message/thank%20you`  <<  it gives a "The requested resource is not available." error

Here is my file content:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ2Rk.png)

Comment: have a look at below repo for learning ,use it on jboss for tomcat you may need some change in web.xml https://github.com/rksharma1401/java-rest-easy-demo